# How can I load a list of object into select tag with Ajax through API Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of options inside a 'select' tag. For whichever option is selected, an 'onchange' function will be activated which carries on the value of that option. A function which activated will use Ajax to call to a controller to get a list of data that I can store into my others 'select' tag. How can I achieve this?

My HTML:

```
<select id="category-select" onchange="GetEmployee()">
   <option value="0" selected>ALL CATEGORY</option>
   <option value="144">Food Category</option>
   <option value="177">Music Category</option>
</select>
<select id="employeeDisplay" multiple>
</select>
```

My JS:

```
function GetEmployee() {
    var MaNguoiDung = 120;
    var MaThuMuc = document.getElementById("category-select").value;
    $('#employeeDisplay').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "MaNguoiDung": MaNguoiDung,
                "MaThuMuc": MaThuMuc
            },
            url: "/get-nhan-vien?MaNguoiDung=" + MaNguoiDung + "&MaThuMuc=" + MaThuMuc,
            success: function () {
                alert('Get Success');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The alert was only to test if my ajax can run or not. Apparently, it can't. Also, I need to know how to stored query data into the second 'select'. Like after the URL attribute, I don't know what to write next after that. Sorry but I'm completely new in Ajax. Some referencing and tutorial online mostly shown how to load ajax into the table. There might be more but table is the only thing I can find so I'm very in need of a way to store it into select.

Edit: This is the response data I receive from my Controller

> [Sample JSON](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.4a4e72e4f55e4d89ac61bb1b639131a2&right=local.fegezo)

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with the code shown.

1. The `<select>` you have the onchange in is not the same one you target to get value inside the function.
2. You are creating a new change event inside the function called by `onchange`. That new jQuery `change()` won't fire until next time you edit the `<select>`
3. You are manually creating the url query string but also providing a data object. Internally jQuery takes that object and will add it to the query string you manually created, effectively duplicating the parameters

So, lets get rid of the `onchange` , give the `<select>` an id and fix the query string in the ajax. Also you want an error handler to help troubleshooting

As for how to handle the response will need to see a sample of it first

HTML

```
<select id="category-select">
   <option value="0" selected>ALL CATEGORY</option>
   <option value="144">Food Category</option>
   <option value="177">Music Category</option>
</select>
<select id="employeeDisplay" multiple>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $('#category-select').change(function () {
        var category = this.value;
        // I don't know which variable is which in `data`
        var MaNguoiDung = 120;// is this category ???
        var MaThuMuc = null // confused where this comes from because other select is empty

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "MaNguoiDung": MaNguoiDung, 
                "MaThuMuc": MaThuMuc
            },
            url: "/get-nhan-vien",
            success: function (response) {
                              // ^^ missing argument needed to receive the data
                console.log(response)// log it to console for now
                alert('Get Success');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, message){
                  console.log('Status: ', status, ', Message: ', message)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh shoot! I just realise the part about select id. Sorry about that. It's 1 AM at my place and I kinda sleepy. About the variable part, 'MaNguoiDung' currently is a fixed variable with value of 120. 'MaThuMuc' value is based on the selected option of my 'category select. That's why I put 'onchange' there. Each time I change the selected option. It will call to the function GetEmployee and load new list of options to my select 'employeeDisplay'.

Comment: OK. That's what my new `$('#category-select').change` will do also and as my variable `category` suggests will be the new selected option value

Comment: I just edit my question with the response json.

Comment: Note you can inspect the actual request in dev tools network and see exactly what url was created, what status is, and what the actual response body looks like among other things like headers , cookies etc

Comment: That was my bad...again I'm sorry about that. I forgot to remove the 'onchange' and switch to Jquery trigger. But after I doing everything exactly as you write, the console print out nothing at all. And when I going into my js file, it said that $ is not defined.

Comment: Ok try changing first line to `jQuery(function($){..` and make sure jQuery.js is loaded before this code

Comment: That one is fixed. It seems that I'm using a very old version of Jquery.js but the console still prints nothing. Edit: Figure out what was wrong and manage to make the function running. It returns me with a data response like this '{data: Array(10)}' which consists of the right items. Now what I need is how to display/stored them in other select. What I need is the 'id' to become value and 'hoTen' to become text, please.